# if isset for checkbox id?

Tags: php, forms, isset

I have a checkbox like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="power" id="electrical">
```

So, can I check in PHP whether the checkbox is checked or not like this

```
if(isset($_POST['electrical']))
```

I know that $_POST is used with field names only, but how to get the field with it's id in PHP?

Thanks

Comment: You don't. The id is never send to the server.

Comment: You should do a `vardump` of `POST` to see what the value of your checkbox is.

Comment: It's hard to answer specifically without a bit more context, but I suspect we're dealing with an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.  Why do you think you need the id?  You might need to start renaming your checkboxes, or you might want to start using the value attribute, but without context, we can't tell for certain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can't read the `id`, but the `name` & `value` only, a solution would be, to put the ID in the name too like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="power[electrical]" id="electrical" value="test">
```

The value will then go to:

```
$_POST['power']['electrical']
```

Or store the `ID` in the value field

```
<input type="checkbox" name="power[electrical]" id="electrical" value="electrical">
```

You will then find it here: `$_POST['power']`

When you have multiple checkboxes of the same `name`, you should go with my first solution